# why $\sum_{g∈G}\overline {h(g)}χ_v(g)$ is scalar of identity map of $V$ and what is the scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, characters

Let ($χ,V$) be a irreducible representation and $h$ be class function.
Then, why
$\sum_{g∈G}\overline {h(g)}χ_v(g)$ is scalar of identity map of $V$ ?

(I try to prove find the relation between $\sum_{g∈G}\overline {h(g)}χ_v(g)$ and
$J＝$$\sum_{g∈G}\overline {χ(g)}γ_v(g)$（$γ_v$ is character of ($χ,V$)).
The latter is scalar, and I want to prove the former is multiple of $Id_V$ by scalar using the latter.)

And **I want to know why the scalar is J｜G｜/dimV**.

Thank you in advance.

*P.S.* Exsitence of scalar is guaranteed by Shur's lemma. Thank you for a comment.

Comment: Have you tried to use Schur's lemma?

Comment: If the field is algebraically closed then let $Tv = \sum_{g\in G} \overline{h(g)} gv$ and $a$ an eigenvalue, you'll get that $T-aI$ commutes with $G$ so its kernel is $G$-invariant, the kernel is also a non-empty subspace, therefore it must be the whole of $V$ for $(G,V)$ to be irreducible, and hence $T=aI$.
If $char(K)\nmid \dim V$ then $a = \frac{tr(T)}{\dim V}$.

Comment: Could you tell me why $a＝tr(T)/dimV$?